# mod_rewrite GUI?

Tags: .htaccess, user-interface, mod-rewrite

Anyone have a graphical tool for developing mod_rewrite rules.

Ideally it would display a pipeline of rewrites and then when given an instance of a uri would show the transforms as the get applied.

It's always a pain to get them setup just right so any way of making it easier would help.

Comment: I don't know of any... that sounds like an interesting open source project...

Comment: Interesting idea.  If we only knew some excellent programmers who have some spare time.  You could add a bounty to this question for the first person to create the app and post a download link!  :-)

Answer (score 8):

For online testing of .htaccess (read: mod_rewrite) rules, try:

http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

It shows you what and how rules are applied to the input URL.

Answer (score 5):

I dont know of any downloadable tools but there are a few helpful sites that I use to get the basics done:

http://www.webmaster-toolkit.com/mod_rewrite-rewriterule-generator.shtml

http://www.thejackol.com/htaccess-cheatsheet/

Answer (score 5):

I think it’s quite hard to write one. Because mod_rewrite’s behavior is heavily dependent on the environment it’s used in.

Take for an example the `-f` expression for the [`RewriteCond` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) to test if *TestString* exists and is a regular file in the file system. How would you do this without the actual file system?

Though the basic behavior (just the `RewriteRule` directive) could be implemented.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any such tool. The way I've addressed this problem was through a set of unit tests that are checking the correctness of my rules. If you want to have your tests always in synch with the config, you'll have to configure your tests to read the load the rules directly from the config file.

./alex

Answer (score 0):

There is also a new webapp developed by technicalseo.com with help of mwl.be api they have nice gui with same functionality.

https://technicalseo.com/tools/htaccess/

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like you're looking for an app like [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/).

Comment: Nope, problem isn't the regular expressions, it's the way in which the rules interact with each other.