# Rewrite rule generator?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Anybody know an online tool to generate Apache `mod_rewrite` rules to point people with simple .htaccess questions to?

I'm thinking of simple standard scenarios:

- Simple redirects (`url1`=>`url2`)
- Removing / adding `www.`
- `/a/b/c/d` to `index.php?value1=a&value2=b...`

and so on and so on....

I'm asking because most mod_rewrite questions turning up on SO could be answered with a link to that, and help people help themselves (well, help as far as "help" goes with a generator tool that can be used without actually having to learn how things work.)

Comment: On a semi-related note, I'm working on something in response to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3417039/a-tool-to-debug-and-test-mod-rewrite-htaccess-directives)...but shh, it's a secret (actually I just got lazy/busy and need to get back to working on it). Also, you reminded me that I should take a stab at writing the `mod_rewrite` tag wiki...

Comment: @Tim nice, feel free to add if something comes out of it! That sounds interesting.

Comment: @Pekka웃, I know this is old, but it is generating activity (with link answers) and it off-topic for new standards of SO, I will close vote it please tell me if you think you can get it on-topic or that I'm wrong so I can retract my vote.

Comment: @Petter it's definitely off topic by today's standards; no point trying to change that, IMO.

Comment: May be https://htaccess.xyz ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Even more such questions could be solved with a link to the [manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteRule).

If we provide only a link to a generator, the answer has no educational value, and will result only in more trivial questions asked. I'd recommend reading [answers to this question form meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions), which contains some relevant discussion.

That said, a quick [google search](http://www.google.pl/search?q=apache+rewrite+rule+generator) has returned some useful results:

- http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/ generates rules for `/c/d` => `index.php?a=b&c=d`
- http://tools-for-webmasters.com/mod_rewrite_tool.html this one currently moved to https://www.301-redirect.online/htaccess-rewrite-generator

Comment: +1 both nice! Re the 2nd paragraph: I doubt the influx of trivial questions can be stopped either way. (I have asked a related question on [Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62258/what-can-be-done-about-repetitive-questions)) I'm rather looking for a lazy way to give a useful answer. The manual is too complex for people who know nothing about Apache; your tutorial link looks interesting, though.

Comment: @Pekka: There will always be new users who will ask trivial questions, but I think that it's important to teach them to try and learn themselves, so they won't do it again (and become better programmers along the way).

Answer (score 5):

A [cheap google search](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ix=seb&ie=UTF-8&ion=1#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&site=webhp&source=hp&q=htaccess%20rewrite%20generator&pbx=1&oq=&aq=&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&fp=a7dac6c7c9d798b5&ix=seb&ion=1&ix=seb&ion=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=a7dac6c7c9d798b5&biw=1280&bih=938&ix=seb&ion=1) has two that exist.

I've tried three so far. I like this one the most so far:

- Generate it - http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/
- <s>htaccess url rewrite generator - http://www.myseotool.com/free-seo-tools/htaccess-url-rewrite-generator.php</s> Doesn't work anymore.

Also, if you need a tool to test these results:

- apache rewrite tester: http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/