# How to Simulate & Test URL rewrite rule in Apache 2, when on sharehosting RewriteLog is disabled/unallowed in .Htaccess?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting, apache2

How to Simulate & Check a URL rewrite rule in Apache 2, when on sharehosting RewriteLog is disabled and or *NOT* allowed to be set in .Htaccess? In other words, are there any tools/simulators to test an url rewrite independantly of hosting, to check see for possibel Rewrite loops etc?

Thanks!

Answer (score 21):

I enjoy using http://htaccess.madewithlove.be

However, things like

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

won't work, yet.

Comment: The use of %{THE_REQUEST} is not supported either

Answer (score 0):

I use [Mod Rewrite Generator](http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/index.php) to generate and test my RewriteRule.
It takes care of the negations as well.
It also lets you modify the URL as per your needs.

Comment: Nice, but very specific to transforming folders into parameters. Does not support more complex transformations, such as parameters to folders.